# Select2 still has --focus class when select is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 and i disabled one of my selects but bcs of library select2 i've got class select2-container--focus on span but when i try to get this span and remove this class i've got null

html

```
<div class="custom-select" id="id_section_div">
    <select name="contractor_section" class="form-select select2-hidden-accessible" id="id_contractor_section"
            multiple="" data-select2-id="select2-data-id_contractor_section" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
            disabled="disabled">
        <option value="1">1-ДУ1</option>

    </select>
    <span
        class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--disabled select2-container--focus"
        dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-5-zpeu" style="width: 601.984px;">
    </span>
</div>
```

js file

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#id_contractor_section').select2();
        });

        var contractor_object = document.getElementById('id_contractor_object')

        const divSection = document.querySelector('#id_section_div')
        const getSpan = divSection.querySelector('span')

        console.log(getSpan)

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_contractor_section").attr("disabled", "true");

            if (contractor_object.value) {
                $("#id_contractor_section").removeAttr("disabled");
            }

            $("#id_contractor_object").on("change", function () {
                $("#id_contractor_section").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        });
```

and it looks like that
[image]

[image]